# Compile-time check whether output (<<) and relational (<, >, etc.) are available

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently using the `is_call_possible` 3rd party code

https://github.com/jaredhoberock/is_call_possible

to figure out at compile time if a member is available. This example works great:

```
#include <string>
#include "is_call_possible.h"

DEFINE_IS_CALL_POSSIBLE(is_call_possible, operator())
DEFINE_IS_CALL_POSSIBLE(test_available, test)

struct Foo {
  void operator()(double) {}
  double test(std::string) { return 0; }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  static_assert(is_call_possible<Foo, void(double)>::value,"err"); //success
  static_assert(test_available<Foo, double(std::string)>::value,"err"); //success
  return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work on ordinary non-members so I can't do the same for the output and relational operators:

```
DEFINE_IS_CALL_POSSIBLE(output_available, operator<<) //error
DEFINE_IS_CALL_POSSIBLE(less_available, operator<) //error
DEFINE_IS_CALL_POSSIBLE(greater_available, operator>) //error
```

Can you point me to convenient 3rd party code (or your own code) to accommodate this?

The underlying solution (the "3rd party code") can be implemented in C++11 if it's easier, but I guess I won't notice the difference in my own code (as a user of the 3rd party code).

Comment: @KennyTM Sure the solution can be in C++11 if it's easier, but I guess I won't feel the difference in my own code. I've updated the question to mention this.

Comment: What is the error you're getting at the lines you've marked `//error`?

Comment: @KenWhite For the first `//error` line (the output << operator), I get 4 errors, the first one `Overloaded 'operator<<' must be a binary operator (has 3 parameters)`. The other three are the same, except `4 parameters`, `1 parameter` and `5 parameters` instead of `3 parameters`. I'm using Clang.

Comment: It's possible that this code doesn't support non-members, but that's not the cause of this particular compiler error. It's because this particular definition of `DEFINE_IS_CALL_POSSIBLE` generates functions with the same name as the 2nd argument, i.e. `operator<<` in your case, with between 1 and 5 arguments. But the operators have pre-defined signatures. For example, the ones you list must be binary. So you get the errors for 1, 3, 4, 5 argument definitions. You could make a specialized binary-only version of that file that should work for your operators.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C++11 is an option, the `decltype` compile-time construction can be used in conjunction with SFINAE to basically do 'concept checks' on types (despite the lack of true concept checking in the C++11 standard), to see if they support operations.

(untested as I lack a C++11 compiler at the moment [curse you Windows~!], but I'm sure someone will catch my errors if they exist).

Ex.

```
template<typename T> struct voidify{typedef void type;};
template<typename T, typename U, typename enable=void>
struct has_operator_less {
  enum{value=false};
};
template<typename T, typename U>
struct has_operator_less<T, U, typename voidify<decltype(
  std::declval<T>() < std::declval<U>() // <-- this is the 'concept' check
)>::type> {
  enum{value=true};
};
```

And you use this to enable/disable with the `std::enable_if` construct on any functions dependent on the presence or absence of `operator<` existing for those two types:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<
  has_operator_less<T, U>::value, I_am_the_result_type_of_the_function
>::type
I_depend_on_the_existence_of_the_less_than_operator(const T& a, const U& b) {...}
```

And if you want an alternative implementation of the function for types that lack the `operator<`, you just enable with the negation:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<
  !has_operator_less<T, U>::value, I_am_the_result_type_of_the_function
  // ^ note the negation
>::type
I_depend_on_the_existence_of_the_less_than_operator(const T& a, const U& b) {...}
```

So now you have implementations that are determined at compile time for types that have and types that don't have those operators, and this solution can be repeated for any other operators or function names or *anything* you want. Just place the concept you're checking in the `decltype`.

And none of this requires having a separate configuration step before the build.

(again, untested code -.-' but pretty sure correct; the rest of y'all know where the edit button is :-P )

Comment: This technique is indeed the nec-plus-ultra short of actual concepts -- but as a side-note, because the implementation relies on SFINAE, it in turns require that what is being checked also plays nice with SFINAE. For instance `std::reverse_iterator<T>` always provides an `operator<`, although it is incorrect to instantiate it with a bidirectional iterator (or less). So in this case you would get a false positive. Sometimes it's worse and it is even impossible to perform the check without triggering the invalid instantation we want to avoid.

Comment: @LucDanton Fair point. Although, if it were me, and if I required that much specificity, I'd just add in additional concept checks (ex. as with std::iterator_traits<>::iterator_category). Additionally, I'd normally expect someone seeing a language construct they're not familiar with to either research it or ask another question, so I watered down the concepts to the point of Newtonian 'vulgar mechanick' usability, and question whether or not it would be an 'improvement' to add in the extra info. That said... If requested I could find a link to a more comprehensive tutorial, or write some more.

Comment: Arguably you didn't water down anything. This is all there is. If you start writing some 'plumbing' around non-SFINAE friendly code, this plumbing itself will need to be SFINAE friendly -- so you use and reuse the same technique. (I wasn't making a point or counterpoint.)

Answer (score 0):

[Boost Type Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) will do this.

Note: there are still be issues with template code (no matter which of the methods you use to detect it).  For instance, `vector<T>::operator<` assumes that `T` has an `operator<`, so you get the following:

```
struct Silly {};

std::cout << boost::has_less<Silly>::value << std::endl;  // 0
std::cout << boost::has_less<std::vector<Silly>>::value << std::endl;  // 1
```